# Client/server широковещательный запрос

Tags: c, сокет

Создаю программу клиент сервер, в которой при запуске сервера в аргументах можно указать порт и максимальное количество подключений. В клиенте при его запуске нужно реализовать отправку широковещательного запроса с чем и возникли трудности. Мне нужно что бы клиент отправлял широковещательный запрос для уведомления сервера о том что он есть.
код сервера :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DEFPORT 5000
#define DEFNUM  3

typedef struct options {
    int port;
    int number;
} info_t;

/*
 * ip port
 * number of connection for work
 */
static int server(int port, int nmax)
{
        int sock;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        int mysock;
        char buff[1024];
        int rval;
    int n = 0;

        /* Create socket */

        sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sock < 0) {
                perror("create socet failure");
        return -1;
        }

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons(port);

        /* Call bind */

        if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))) {
                perror("bind failed");
        return -1;
        }
        /*listen*/

        listen(sock, 5);

        /* Accept */

        while (n < nmax) {
                mysock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) 0, 0);
                if (mysock == -1) {
                        perror("accept failed");
                } else {
                        memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
                        if ((rval = recv(mysock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0)) < 0) {
                                perror("reading stream message error");
            } else if (rval == 0) {
                                printf("Ending connection\n");
            } else {
                                printf("MSG: %s\n",buff);
                            printf("Got message (rval = %d)\n", rval);
                n++;
            }
                        close(mysock);
                }
    }
        return 0;
}

static void parse_args(int argc, char *argv[], info_t *info)
{
    int rez = 0;
    int p = info->port, n = info->number;

    while ((rez = getopt(argc, argv, "p:n:h")) != -1) {
        switch (rez) {
            case 'p': 
                p = atoi(optarg);
                if (p <= 0 || p >= 65535) p = DEFPORT;
                break;
            case 'n':
                n = atoi(optarg);
                if (n <= 0) n = DEFNUM;
                break;
            case 'h':
                printf("\nUsage:\n\t-p PORT; -n NUMBER\n\n");
                exit(0);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    info->port = p;
    info->number = n;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    info_t info = {
        .port = DEFPORT,
        .number = DEFNUM
    };

    parse_args(argc, argv, &info);
    server(info.port, info.number);

    return 0;
}
```

код клиента:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DATA "HI MANN"

/*
 * ip mask
 * ip port
 * message
 */

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int sock;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        struct hostent *hp;
        char buff[1024];
    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = (5000);

    if (argc > 1){
        ip = argv[1];
    }

        sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(sock < 0){
                perror("не удалось создать сокет");
                return -1;
        }

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    printf("send to: %s\n", ip);
        hp = gethostbyname(ip);
    if(hp == 0){
                perror("gethostbyname failed");
                close(sock);
                return -1;
        }
    
        memcpy(&server.sin_addr,hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
        server.sin_port = htons (port);
        
        if(connect (sock,(struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
                perror("connect failed");
                close(sock);
                return -1;
        }
    
        if(send(sock,DATA, sizeof(DATA), 0) < 0){
                perror("send failed");
                close(sock);
                return -1;
        }

        printf("sent %s\n", DATA);
        close(sock);
        return -1;
}
```

---

Клиент должен при включении сообщать о себе, после чего устанавливается связь. Вот мо задача. IP адрес сервера неизвестен известен только порт. На сервере стоит ограниченное количество подключений и не факт что клиент возьмет и подключится. А вот серверу необходимо знать сколько у него есть клиентов которые могут к нему подключиться, тем более и клиент и сервер будут стоять на каждой машине. Но формально роль сервера будет выполнять только один пк. И ему нужно знать о всех клиентах, для этого  нужно что бы клиент при включении сообщал серверу что он есть. И если будет нужно связь будет установлена либо с одной стороны либо с другой.

Comment: А зачем клиенту отправлять широковещательный запрос о том, что он есть, если он может взять и подключится? или сервер должен уметь ответь на такой запрос с параметрами подключения?

Comment: INADDR_BROADCADT

Comment: Широковещательный запрос в  AF_INET возможен только для SOCK_DGRAM (udp) сокетов

Comment: @Олег Кутовенко  > И если будет нужно связь будет установлена либо с одной стороны либо с другой.  -  TCP так не работает. Нельзя подключатся с "двух сторон". Хотя если у Вас программа будет работать и как сервер и как клиент одновременно, то теоретически она может это сделать.  Может озвучите более высокоуровнево свою задачу? Очень похоже на классическую. XY-задачу.   Но в любом случае, похоже, что легче все сделать на UDP.

Comment: Приложение опрашивает компьютеры которые находятся в локальной сети, получает ответ о том сколько пк активно, все вопрос только обнаружения активных подключенных к сети ПК.

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно что бы клиент отправлял широковещательный запрос для
> уведомления сервера о том что он есть.

То, что Вы описали, очень похоже на первую фазу протокола DHCP. Не вдаваясь в детали, это можно описать так:

1. Клиент: "Есть в сети сервера?" (Широковещательный)
2. Сервер: "Да, я тут есть!". (По IP отправителя пункта 1)
3. Клиент: "А можно с тобой установить соединение?" (По IP из пункта 2)
4. Сервер: "Да, выделяю тебе порт № на время N секунд)"
5. Клиент: "Соединяюсь по IP сервера и порту, который мне выделен"

Answer (score 0):

Все так, механизм похож, только приложение не выдает IP адреса да и работает на другом уровне модели OSI. Просто сервер не знает о том сколько у него,а 1 шаг DHCP это заявление клиента что он есть, у меня же наоборот. В общем случае без деталей мне нужно реализовать широковещательный SOCKET сервер и клиент используя СИ.